# Android - Strange crash reports when sending the user to android play for the app

Tags: android

I have a button that the user can click which sends them to the app page in the Google Play store. This is the code I use for the button:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.problemio"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

and the package is here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.problemio

and sometimes it works fine, but sometimes I get a crash report like this:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.problemio }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2833)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2959)
at com.problemio.content.BusinessIdeasActivity$5.onClick(BusinessIdeasActivity.java:107)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea why it only sometimes works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try a bit different URL for your software:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.problemio");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    try {
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // Hmm, market is not installed
        Log.w(TAG, "Android Market is not installed");
    }
```

Comment: thanks - what is a smart check, but I think there could be a web version of the market I could send them to...no?

Comment: if you try to open URL which starts with `http://market...`, if the phone has Google Play installed, the system will ask, if the user wants to open using browser or the market, otherwise it just opens in the browser. you may put opening `http://` url in the catch statement, so if there's no market, it should open in the browser directly.

Answer (score 3):

This would happen on devices that don't have the Android Market/Google Play installed. There are actually quite a few of those, especially cheapish tablets. You can catch the exception of check if the market/play app is installed to prevent this from happening.

BTW, if you are only distributing on the Market/Play Store, your app might have been pirated, or maybe someone just took it off their rooted device and pushed it on their new el cheapo tablet or the emulator.

Comment: good point about the rooted devices :) Do you think if they dont have market installed, I should just take them to the web version of the android store?

Comment: Yes, and it it actually the recommended approach. Custom schemes like `market://` are now discouraged. BTW, if the Market app is available, you should get a dialog so you can choose whether to open the link with the app or the browser if the format is `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=maypackagename`

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.problemio"));
    startActivity(viewIntent);
}catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
    Log.e("helloandroid", "Call failed",activityException);
}
```

try this, now your app wont crash but may have exception.

Comment: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.problemio will be internally navigated to  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.problemio